# Are abstract classes a good way to avoid rewriting the same code?

Tags: oop

If I have many classes which are pretty similar with each other then, does making them inherit from an abstract class a good option?

Comment: You should provide code samples, elaborate more on what's really similar in  your case...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only if they are a true abstraction in the Dog is an Animal kind of sense. Stuff on your abstract classes must make sense to all derived.

Otherwise you risk using your base class to sort of import an API. Although you see some frameworks do this, without deliberate design you are usually better off extracting the commonality out to shared dependencies which all the classes commonly use.

Abstract classes that no client code directly references or uses is typically a sign you may be running off track.

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely. Though I would use an interface/protocol where possible. They're more flexible, as they give you the freedom to inherit another class.

The best choice depends on the nature of your classes, and what their duplicated code is.